Asymptotics on inverse error function around -1
I am trying to find the asymptotic behaviour of $\operatorname{erf}^{-1}(y)$ as $y \to -1$. I know that $1+\operatorname{erf}(x/\sqrt{2}) \sim 2\frac{\exp(-x^2/2)}{-x\sqrt{2\pi}}$ as $x \to -\infty$, but can this asymptote be inverted? It seems that this question has not been asked on stackexchange either.

Wolfram functions has such an expression

@TymaGaidash Unfortunately, the link you provided has an expression for the inverse error function as $y \to 1$ instead of as $y \to -1$. Thank you nevertheless.

You can use $\text{erf}^{-1}(-x)=-\text{erf}^{-1}(x)$ or symmetry with the above link to get the expression

I see, this makes a lot of sense.

You can simplify the problem by focusing on the behaviour of the inverse complementary error function near $0$. This is because
$$
\operatorname{erf}^{ - 1} (x) =  - \operatorname{erf}^{ - 1} ( - x) =  - \operatorname{erfc}^{ - 1} (1 + x).
$$
By utilising $\S7.17$(iii) with $\operatorname{inverfc}=\operatorname{erfc}^{-1}$ and substituting $1+x$ for $x$, you can determine the asymptotic behaviour of $\operatorname{erf}^{-1}(x)$ as $x \to -1^+$.

Thank you for all the answers. Based on the answers on this post I was able to come up with a proof myself (for the slightly adjusted CDF of standard normal $\Phi$ instead of erf). I post it here for any other visitors. Let $\phi(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \Phi(x)$.
So, we want to show that
$$ \Phi(x) \sim \frac{\phi(x)}{-x} \;\;\text{ as }\;\; x \to - \infty$$
and
$$ \Phi^{-1}(y) \sim - \sqrt{-2\ln y} \;\;\text{ as }\;\; y \to 0^+,$$
where $a_n \sim b_n \iff \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n / a_n = 1$.
Proof
Integration by parts provides upper and lower bounds on $\Phi(x)$ for $x < 0$:
$$\Phi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \phi(s) ds = \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{\frac{d}{ds} \phi(s)}{-s} ds = \frac{\phi(x)}{-x} - \underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{\phi(s)}{s^2} ds}_{\geq 0}$$
$$= \frac{\phi(x)}{-x} - \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{\frac{d}{ds}\phi(s)}{-s^3} ds = \frac{\phi(x)}{-x} - \frac{\phi(x)}{-x^3} + 3 \underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{\phi(s)}{s^4} ds}_{\geq 0}.$$
Regarding $\Phi^{-1}(x)$ we perform a change of variable based on $\lim_{x \to -\infty} \Phi(x) = 0$:
$$
    \lim_{y \to 0^+} \frac{-\sqrt{-2\ln y}}{\Phi^{-1}(y)} = \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{-\sqrt{-2\ln \Phi(x)}}{\Phi^{-1}(\Phi(x))} = \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{-\sqrt{-2\ln \Phi(x)}}{x}.
$$
Now, since $-2\ln \phi(x) = x^2 +\ln 2\pi$ one may reuse the upper and lower bounds on $\Phi$ to obtain that $\lim_{y \to 0^+} -\sqrt{-2\ln y} \bigg / \Phi^{-1}(y) = 1$.
I terms of fidelity of the asymptotics one gets the following two graphs (ground truth in solid orange and asymptotic in dashed purple):



The first relation you derived is indeed correct. Unfortunately it is also obvious that its inverse can not be expressed in elementary functions. Instead you derive a limit, but it is not clear at all whether this "approximation" is meaningful.

The OP is looking for a simple formula for the inverse of the error function. Here is one approach to obtain such a formula.
Define $I$ as the integral from $-L$ to $+L$ of the (normalized) Gaussian. Multiply this by the same expression, making $I^2$ a two-dimensional integral over a square region. Replace the square region by a circle around the origin with the same area $\pi R^2 = 4L^2$. After introducing polar coordinates the new integral is straightforward and yields $I^2 = 1 - \exp(-R^2/2)$. On the other hand we have $I = 1 - 2\Phi$. Solving these equations we obtain a formula for $L$ in terms of the error function $\Phi$:
$$L^2 = -\frac{\pi}{2} \ln(4 \Phi(1-\Phi))$$
I have not tested how well this asymptotic formula works. It is possible that the pre-factor $\pi /2$ should be adjusted slightly to give more accurate results. The reason is that we replaced an integral over a square region by one over a circular region. This may cause numerical effects.

Could you elaborate on why changing the integral from one over a square region to one over a circular region does not affect the result too much? It seems that we are integrating over a different region and thus different function values. Are there useful statements about the absolute or relative error of such an operation?

As long as the function does not vary too much the approximation should work fine. Note that you can also derive two inequalities by replacing the square by an inner circle $(R = L)$ or an outer circle $(R = \sqrt {2}L)$.

Well, the pdf of gaussians decays quite rapidly so it is not obvious to me that the function does not vary too much. I see, but then the expression for L is loose up to a constant factor of $\sqrt{2}$, i.e. we do not quite know the exact asymptotic behaviour.

It is important to note that the boundary region between square and circle is fairly small. Furthermore the difference in the integrals consists of contributions with opposite signs. Therefore a lot of cancellation takes place. I estimate that the relative error is no more than $2$ %, which is pretty good for a simple formula.

The point of my post is that a math problem can sometimes be dealt with in an intuitive way. Of course more analytical approaches are valid, but in many cases they do not lead to a simple formula that can be inverted.

I see, thanks for the post.
